# Flutter ListView.builder's UI not getting updated by getx even if it receives updated data

Tags: flutter, setstate, state-management, flutter-getx

I am beginner trying to learn getx with flutter, This is my controller

```
class QuestionAnswers_Getx extends GetxController {
  final _questionandanswers = <QA>[].obs;
  List<QA> get questionandanswers => _questionandanswers;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getall_questionandanswers();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,()=>listen_firebase());
  }


  getall_questionandanswers() async {
    await qaref.get().then((QuerySnapshot query){
      _questionandanswers.addAll(query.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) => doc_to_obj(doc)).toList());
    });
  }

  listen_firebase() async {
    await qaref.snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          
          querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach((DocumentChange doc) {         
              if(doc.type==DocumentChangeType.added){
                  _questionandanswers.add(doc_to_obj(doc.doc));          
              }else if(doc.type==DocumentChangeType.modified){
                _questionandanswers[doc.newIndex] = doc_to_obj(doc.doc);
                // print(_questionandanswers[doc.newIndex]);
              }else if(doc.type==DocumentChangeType.removed){
                print("getx--------------removed line");
              }
          });
     });

  }

}
```

And this is my Obx widget where i want to use controller's data.I have used get.put in previous pages and finding the controller here

```
final qa_controller = Get.find<QuestionAnswers_Getx>();
Obx(() {
              RxList<QA> myqa = <QA>[].obs;
              myqa.addAll( qa_controller.questionandanswers.where((element)=>element.user_name=="Jaswant patil").toList()   );                
//here if i use print(myqa[0].answer) then it gives me old as well as new data for answer parameter
                  return ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,   
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: myqa.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                          return QAwidget(
                              answer: myqa[index].answer,
                              comment_count: myqa[index].comment_count,
                              upvotes: myqa[index].upvotes,
                              user_image_url:
                                  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/24/06/33/crescent-4875339__340.jpg",
                              user_name: myqa[index].user_name,
                              user_occupation: myqa[index].user_occupation,
                              post_image_url: myqa[index].post_image_url,
                              category: myqa[index].category,
                              hasimage: myqa[index].hasimage,
                              question: myqa[index].question);
                      },
```

The above ListView displays the initial data correctly in Ui but doesn't display the updated UI when data is changed even if is receiving the updated data.But when i swap the pages and again come back to this page updated data is displayed , i think need to call the setState on data change but don't know where to put it.

Thank you for the answers and pls forgive for whatever grammatical mistakes present in above question

Comment: is `QAwidget` stateful?

Comment: No QAwidget is not stateful

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use variablename.value.addAll
Of that doesn't work
You can always refresh the variable, observables have a method call refresh() I think